# Apache AVRO with Rest

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, avro

I am evaluating using Apache AVRO for my Jersey REST services. I am using Springboot with Jersey REST.

Currently I am accepting JSON as input which are converted to Java Pojos using the Jackson object mapper.

I have looked in different places but I cannot find any example that is using Apache AVRO with a Jersey end point.

I have found this Github repository (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/) which has Apache AVRO plugin.

I still cannot find any good example as how to integrate this. Has anyone used Apache AVRO with Jersey? If yes, is there any example I can use?

Comment: Some useful links : https://github.com/keedio/avro-schema-repo/tree/master/client/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/repo/client

https://pastebin.com/DNS8xntG

Comment: Did you take a look at the test folder: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/tree/master/avro/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/avro ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To start , two things need to happen:

1. You need to [develop a custom `ObjectMapper`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/tree/master/avro#creating-objectmapper) after the fashion of the Avro schema format
2. You need to [supply that custom `ObjectMapper`](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json) to Jersey.

That should look something like this:

```
@Provider
public class AvroMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final AvroMapper avroMapper = new AvroMapper();

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return avroMapper;
    }
}
```

[Configure your application](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json) to use Jackson as the message handler:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
         super(JacksonFeature.class,AvroMapperProvider.class);
    }
}
```

---

**Alternatively,** you can implement a custom [`MessageBodyReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) and [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) that allows you to directly process the payloads on the way in and out:

```
public class AvroMessageReader implements MessageBodyReader<Person> {

    AvroSchema schema;

    final AvroMapper avroMapper = new AvroMapper();

    public AvroMessageReader(){
        schema = avroMapper.schemaFor(Person.class); //generates an Avro schema from the POJO class.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {
        return type == Person.class; //determines that this reader can handle the Person class.
    }

    @Override
    public Person readFrom(Class<Person> type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt, MultivaluedMap<String, String> mm, InputStream in) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        return avroMapper.reader(schema).readValue(in);
    }

}
```

Here, we generate an avro schema from a hypothetical Person class. The JAX-RS runtime will select this reader based on the response from `isReadable`.

[You can then inject the `MessageBodyWorkers`](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html) component into your service implementation class:

```
@Path("app")
public static class BodyReaderTest{

    @Context
    private MessageBodyWorkers workers;

    @POST
    @Produces("avro/binary")
    @Consumes("avro/binary")
    public String processMessage() {

        workers.getMessageBodyReader(Person.class, Person.class, new Annotation[]{}, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    }
 }
```

To answer your last comment: [Setting the mime type](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#HTTP+as+Transport) on your handler to the recommended avro/binary ought to do it.

Comment: Thanks. What about the produce and consume in the rest end point. I have   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but the Provider example I've provided here doesn't interfere with the service implementation class @Makky. See if my update provides more clarity

Comment: I think I understand what you were referring to now: setting the mime type? See the update @Makky

Comment: @kolossus For serializing do we need to provide an implmenation of MessageBodyWriter, same as the MessageBodyReader you have above? I didn't get the part about injecting MessageBodyWorkers in the Service class, can I inject it in my controller so that it automaticaly marshalls and unmarshalls POJO(and registered Avro schemas) to Avro?

Comment: @kolossus If method 1, how do I setup Spring Boot application to use Jackson as the message handler? I added the AvroMapperProvider. And will this allow for automatic serialization/deserialization? Or should I choose method 2 MessageBodyWorker for it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a comprehensive demo (which I wrote) on how to use avro in a JAX-RS REST service [at](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/jaxrs-spf4j-demo). The JAX-RS message body readers and writers for avro are implemented [at](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j-jaxrs/tree/master/spf4j-jaxrs-client/src/main/java/org/spf4j/jaxrs/common/providers/avro) and they do support avro binary, json, idiomatic json, csv where applicable. They do provide full support for schema evolution and projections (via the http accept header). There is a list of articles that explain in more detail the demonstrated concepts [at](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/jaxrs-spf4j-demo/wiki). Also this demo project runs live on GKE [at](https://demo.spf4j.org), you can browse at the openapi [at](https://demo.spf4j.org/apiBrowser/index.html). Avro is being used in the project for everything, for logs, for metrics, for profiling.