# spring-cloud-schema-registry-client does not convert to Avro and I get org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, avro, spring-cloud-stream

My goal is to have Spring automaically marshall responses and requests to Avro format from POJO and any Avro schema files automatically. I have tried to no avail for several days to get spring-cloud-schema-registry-client to automatically serialize/deserialze application/avro messages sent back by the controller as a response. The request comes in with the Accept header "application/avro" (I also tried application/emp.v1+avro and other combinations).

No matter what I try, the response message is not automatically deserialized by spring cloud AvroSchemaMessageConverter. As per their [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-schema-registry/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-schema-registry.html#_avro_schema_registry_message_converter_properties), the Avro schema should be automatically inferred from the POJO, and the repsonse should be sent back in Avro out of the box.

The dependency I'm using is

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

My application.yml file has-

```
spring:
   cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          contentType: application/*+avro
    schema:
      avro:
        dynamicSchemaGenerationEnabled: true
```

Can someone please help me understand why this doesn't work and I keep getting the error message -

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList]
```

Do I need to register the schema explicitly?
For eg,, I'm returning a list of Employees POJO.
If needed I can try to generate the Avro schema from the Employee POJO using [jackson-dataformats](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/tree/2.13/avro#generating-avro-schema-from-pojo-definition) and then manually register it with the AvroConverter bean. But as per my understanding this should be done out of the box by spring-cloud-schema-registry.

Additional Information:
My controller returns a list of Employee POJO like

```
ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>
```

I used @EnableSchemRegistryClient in my main class along with @SpringBootApplication.

In my test method I'm using:

```
        MvcResult result = mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(url)
                    //.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .accept("application/avro"))
                    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/avro"))
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898453/apache-avro-with-rest

Comment: @armandino Yes I thought that would help, but alas I'm struggling to get it to work/implement it. I have added my questions to the Comments section of that answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'm no longer a Spring member, and I believe the schema registry is no longer maintained. But it was never its intention to work with the controller to serialize/deserialize payloads. It was meant to work with Spring Cloud Stream own's serialization mechanism (version 1.x).

I'm afraid it would not work in this case without some tinkering on your end to build a serializer that looks up the registry for a given schema and serializes it back and forth. Note you would also need a header with the FQN of the schema in order to query the registry, and caching it would be a must to not impact your app.

Hopefully someone from the Spring team could provide some better insights on this.

Comment: I see, this does help, I was going crazy trying to figure out why it isn't working. I also wnat to use the Spring Cloud Schema Registry Server to provide Avro schemas to clients- can I use that out of the box using the @EnableSchemaRegistryServer annotation with spring-cloud-schema-registry-server dependency?